# Bloom Filter: How to find k hash functions?

Tags: hash, bloom-filter

A Bloom Filter needs k hash functions, which return a value between 0 and m (m is the length of the bit array).
I have to implement such a bloom filter and I already read some theoretical papers about those filter (how they work, how many hash functions you need, how the error behaves etc.)

Now I have two questions about hash functions:

- How do I find k hash functions - which hash functions should I use?
- How do I find hashs functions which return a value between 0 and m? Alternatively, how can I map the output of a hash function to the range 0-m?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use this - http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_hashing

Answer (score 3):

You can use the [Kirsch-Mitzenmacher optimization](https://www.eecs.harvard.edu/~michaelm/postscripts/tr-02-05.pdf):

```
hash_i = hash1 + i * hash2
```

Where hash1 is 32 bit, hash2 is 32 bit. In a look you could use:

```
hash1 = upper 32 bit of a 64 bit hash
hash2 = lower 32 bit of a 64 bit hash
hash = hash1
for(int i=0; i<k; i++) {
    hash += hash2
}
```

Comment: Is this really all there is to the Kirsch-Mitzenmacher optimization? So hash_0 would just be hash1, hash_1 would be hash1 + hash2, hash_2 would be hash1 + hash2 + hash2, and so on.

Comment: Yes, that's it: see the paper (the abstract is very short). Btw there are other optimizations possible, for example "modulo" (which is slow) can be replaced with multiply & shift. But that's a different topic.

Answer (score 0):

You can get a bunch of hash values at one time with a cryptographic hash function like MD5 or SHA.  Divide the cryptographic hash value into **N** m-bit pieces, and treat them just like you would the output of **N** normal hash functions.

Comment: Splitting the result seems like good advice but cryptographic hashes are not considered wise choices for hash-driven data structures, since they are more about making it difficult to get back the input than performing well.

Answer (score 0):

- The characteristics of the k hash functions that should be used are
  given on the wikipedia page: [Bloom Filter](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bloom_filter) and go in the
  **algorithm description** where it says - The requirement of designing k different independent hash functions...
- For good tutorials on universal hashing : [Nice MIT lecture](http://ocw.mit.edu/courses/electrical-engineering-and-computer-science/6-046j-introduction-to-algorithms-sma-5503-fall-2005/video-lectures/lecture-8-universal-hashing-perfect-hashing/)

Answer (score 0):

U could use any hash functions....there are many hash simple hash functions available in the net. 
Refer http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_hash_functions

Use any hash function to get a hash value and in order to get it in the range of 0-m , use the modulus(%) operator.
i.e  bitlocation = hash % m;

it might not be efficient ,but it works...